# Pocketing queen and striker

Tags: carrom

Whilst playing, an opponent pocketed the queen but the striker followed the queen into the pocket.
Does the player put the queen back in the middle plus one of his pieces or just the queen?

Answer (score 1):

The Queen and one or two additional C/M are returned to the board.

The [Laws of Carrom](http://www.carrom.co.uk/laws-of-carrom/#XV) **99** states

> If the Queen and the Striker are pocketed together by a proper stroke, the Queen shall be taken out for placing by the Umpire. An additional C/M shall be taken out for placing and the player shall continue his turn. If the Queen and the Strkier are pocketed together by an improper stroke, the Queen shall be taken out by the Umpire for placing. Two additional C/M shall be taken out for placing by the opponent and the player shall lose his turn.